What are the things conductive to the abandonment of sensual desire?
Sensual desire is the main hindrance of 5 hindrances that limit the positive development of mind.
What are the things conductive to the abandonment of sensual desire?
What are the things someone can practice to abandonment of sensual desire?

We avoid having seeded questions on this site. Please see this answer on Buddhism Meta for an explanation.

Ok. Can you kindly explain the use of self answering option at asking a question?

I agree with you @ruben2020. . But I felt like there's something missing here. Sometimes we limit ourselves to one site/source and try to find everything there. Then those people find lacking resources there. .

You can "abandon" desire and aversion just by intention, to some extent, as some teachers recommend, but for real abandonment, nothing short of Enlightenment is what they say. Part of right intention is "aspiring to renunciation", so it's a goal, not merely a decision. The five hindrances and the senses themselves are said to drop off in the jhanas, but it's temporary. Sense restraint and recollection of foulness of the body, food, etc. are recommended to reduce or manage sense craving, but seeing how things are transient, can't be grasped, and are therefore dukkha and not worth craving would go more to the root of it (see SN 22.83, .85, .100, MN 35, 109 for systematic question and answer method). Disenchantment wouldn't be a matter of forcing yourself not to think about food, it's said to happen automatically when you see well enough. I've heard Ajahn Chah said just not looking at girls doesn't work, because they're always there, but if you get happiness, from meditation, you don't want anything else (from youtube, "DAY 3 Q N A BY AJAHN BRAHM").

Insight into non-harming, metta (hope for well-being) & compassion is what is necessary to abandon sexual desire. Without insight into the harmfulness of non-committed sex and without insight into the burdens of the married life, meditating on impure objects generally won't work.
Also, jhana cannot be attained when there is sexual desire therefore lust for jhana cannot help abandoning any coarse habitual sexual desire.

I understood thus: ‘This thought of sensual desire has arisen in me. This leads to my own affliction, to others’ affliction, and to the affliction of both; it obstructs wisdom, causes difficulties, and leads away from Nibbāna.’ When I considered: ‘This leads to my own affliction,’ it subsided in me; when I considered: ‘This leads to others’ affliction,’ it subsided in me; when I considered: ‘This leads to the affliction of both,’ it subsided in me; when I considered: ‘This obstructs wisdom, causes difficulties, and leads away from Nibbāna,’ it subsided in me. Whenever a thought of sensual desire arose in me, I abandoned it, removed it, did away with it.
MN 19


Develop respect/welfare/care/good hope (mettaṁ) for others. For when you develop respect any malintent (byāpādo) will be given up.
Develop compassion (karuṇaṁ). For when you develop compassion any injuriousness (vihesā) will be given up.
Develop gladness (for other's foremost qualities; muditaṁ). For when you develop gladness any discontent/non-appreciation (arati) will be given up.
Develop equanimity (upekkhaṁ). For when you develop equanimity any aversion/irriation will be given up.
Develop the unattractive (asubhaṁ). For when you develop the unattractive any lust (rāgo) will be given up.
MN 62


There are six(6) things that someone can practice to reduce / abandonment of sensual desire.

Learning how to meditate on impure objects

Devoting oneself to the meditation on the impure

Guarding the sense doors

Moderation in eating

Noble friendship

Suitable conversation


(Commentary to the Satipatthana Sutta)



Further, there are six things which lead to the casting out of sense-desire:
Taking up the sensuously inauspicious subject of meditation;
application for the development of the jhana on the sensuously inauspicious subject of meditation;
the guarded state of the controlling faculties of sense;
moderation in food;
the sympathy and support of good men in the endeavor;
stimulating talk that helps the accomplishment of the object in view.


Where do you find "commentary" and in which language is it?

Here https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/soma/wayof.html#:~:text=Further%2C%20there%20are,object%20in%20view.
